# Can synchronized blocks be faster than Atomics?

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

Suppose two following counter implementations:

```
class Counter {
  private final AtomicInteger atomic = new AtomicInteger(0);
  private int i = 0;

  public void incrementAtomic() {
    atomic.incrementAndGet();
  }

  public synchronized void increment() {
    i++;
  }
}
```

At first glance atomics should be faster and more scalable. And they are, I believe. But are they faster than `synchronized` blocks all the time? Or some situations exists when this rule is broken (e.g. SMP/Single CPU machine, different CPU ISA, OS'es etc.)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`incrementAndGet` may well be implemented as a CAS-loop. In highly contented situations that can result in *n*-1 of your threads failing leading to an O(*n*) problem, for *n* threads.

( For @Geek:

Typically `getAndIncrement` may be implemented something like:

```
 int old;
 do {
     old = value;
 } while (!compareAndSet(value, old, old+1));
 return old;
```

Imagine you have a *n* threads executing this code on the same atomic, and they happen to be in step with each other. The first iteration does *kn* work. Only one CAS will succeed. The other *n*-1 threads will repeat the exercise until there is only one left. So the total work is O(*n*^2) (worst case) instead of O(*n*). )

Having said that, acquiring a lock will need to do something similar at best, and locks aren't at their best when heavily contended. You're not likely to see much of an advantage for locks until you use a CAS-loop which requires significant computation before get and compareAndSwap.

Comment: can you please elaborate on your first paragraph ?

Answer (score 3):

> Or some situations exists when this rule is broken (e.g. SMP/Single CPU machine, different CPU ISA, OS'es etc.)?

I don't know of any.  (And I stand ready to be corrected ... if someone knows of a concrete counter-example.)

However (and this is my main point) there is no *theoretical* reason why you couldn't have a hardware architecture or a poorly implemented JVM in which `synchronized` is the same speed or faster than the `atomic` types.  (The relative speed of these two forms of synchronization is an *implementation* issue, and as such can only be quantified for existing implementations.)

And of course, this doesn't mean you should never use `synchronized`.  The `synchronized` construct has many use-cases that the atomic classes don't address.

Comment: Yep, atomics guarantee memory visibility, but not mutual execution.

Answer (score 2):

It's implementation dependent - so ultimately you'll need to benchmark on your particualar platform / JVM / configuration.

Having said that, atomics *should* always be faster for the following reasons:

- Atomics are designed so that the JVM can take advantage of atomic machine instructions, which are the fastest atomic operations that you can get for most platforms
- `synchronized` makes use of relatively heavyweight locking schemes with monitor objects, which is designed to protect potentially large blocks of code. This form of locking in inherently more complicated than atomic operations so you would expect it to have higher runtime cost.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said this is implementation dependent . But keep in mind that if your program invariants involve more than one variable , then you **have to use synchronization** to update them together . You can't  do atomic operation on two related variables together just because they are of Atomic type. In that case your only friend is synchronized .

Answer (score -3):

atomic variables will always be faster.

you can see that the java.util.concurrent package always utilises atomic variables rather than synchronized blocks.

Comment: The second statement, while true, doesn't prove anything.  In fact, it only *implies* that atomic types are faster *on average* ... for those particular use-cases ... on the ISA's / platforms that Oracle supports.

Comment: Why? If your second sentence is supposed to provide the reason, it doesn't. It is the *stated purpose* of the concurrent package not to use synchronization anywhere.

Comment: in very few cases of optimistic locking are atomic variables slower, and the reason i mentioned that was to show that they are a preferred solution and are probably the better solution in most cases.

Comment: You still haven't said why; and what the concurrent package does internally isn't evidence of performance; it only shows that the concurrent package meets its design goals. It would be astonishing if it *didn't* use its own classes.