# AtomicInteger Vs synchronized int variable in Java : performance difference

Tags: java, atomic, synchronized, java.util.concurrent

After going through the following question
[Can synchronized blocks be faster than Atomics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11551963/can-synchronized-blocks-be-faster-than-atomics),
I wrote a simple program to compare the performance difference of *AtomicInteger* and synchronized block (incrementing int inside it). Every time I run this program it gives me ratio > 100.
My laptop has Intel Corei3 and following line prints 4.

```
    System.out.println(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors())
```

When I use

```
    THREAD_COUNT = 1;
```

the ratio comes minimum. It varies around 100. For

```
    THREAD_COUNT = 10;
```

ratio is around 800.

**Question 1** : Can you please tell me is this the correct way to test the performance difference of *AtomicInteger* VS synchronized increment() method?

**Question 2** : If I increase `THREAD_COUNT`, ratio increases, why? I think it is because more threads get blocked at synchronized statement and requires more task for CPU. Please comment.

```
package concurrent.atomic;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class Performance {

    private static final AtomicInteger atomicInt = new AtomicInteger(0);
    private static volatile int counter = 0;
    private static final Object LOCK = new Object();
    private static final int THREAD_COUNT = 10;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()); 

        Runnable atomic = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                    int value = atomicInt.incrementAndGet();
                    //if (value % 1000 == 0)
                        //System.out.println("atomic value : "+value);
                }   
            }
        };
        //System.out.println("1");
        Runnable intCounter = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                    synchronized (LOCK) {
                        int value = ++counter;
                        //if (value % 1000 == 0)
                            //System.out.println("sync value "+value);
                    }
                }   
            }
        };

        final ExecutorService atomicExecutor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        final ExecutorService primitiveExecutor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        for (int i = 0; i < THREAD_COUNT ; ++i) {
            atomicExecutor.submit(atomic);
            primitiveExecutor.submit(intCounter);
        }

        while (true) {
            float ratio = (((float) (atomicInt.get() * 1.0) ) / counter) * 100;
            System.out.println("ratio : " + ratio);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://kennethxu.blogspot.in/2009/05/atomicinteger-vs-synchronized-monitor.html does this. Found this googling. Try this.

Comment: You have a bug here, you need to declare `counter` as `volatile`. Otherwise it's not guaranteed that the main thread reads the latest value.

Comment: yes .. i need to change my code.

Comment: Your analysis makes sense. You could maybe reset the counters to 0 from time to time to avoid overflow and more importantly do calculations before and after JIT.

Answer (score 0):

> Question 1 : Can you please tell me is this the correct way to test the performance difference of AtomicInteger VS synchronized increment() method?

There are some subtle problems with your test code:

- If you are synchronizing on `LOCK` then `counter` should not be `volatile`.  Otherwise the `synchronized` code is paying for the lock *and* a `volatile`.
- If `counter` is not `volatile` then you will need to synchronize on `LOCK` when you are reading the value of `counter`.
- You should not be spinning in your main thread.  That's going to be affecting your performance test dramatically.  Put a `Thread.sleep(100);` in your `while` loop at least.
- Turns out that `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()` is pretty expensive on my Mac.  Not sure why.  Switching that to a `while(true)` changed the numbers.

With this then you have a better test of the two although such isolated tests don't really tell us anything other than what you are testing.  Doing a million interrupts in a row is very different then 20 interrupts mixed into real code.

> Question 2 : If I increase THREAD_COUNT, ratio increases, why? I think it is because more threads get blocked at synchronized statement and requires more task for CPU. Please comment.

The `AtomicInteger.incrementAndGet()` works by spinning until a test-and-set succeeds.  This is very different from doing a lock acquisition, increment, and release.  It is very hard to explain what is happening here without knowing the precise operating system thread handling detail and I'm not sure this will be true in all circumstances.

In my tests as the number of threads got more and more above my number of processors, the ratio tended to fluctuate pretty significantly.  As more threads were added the `synchronize` handling obviously suffered from the increased concurrency although I'm not sure what else I can draw from that.