# Java concurrent counter architecture design

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, microservices

Having the following business case:

> Email promotional campaign says that first 1_000_000 users pressing the link will receive a Bonus. Users are going to see either the Bonus or "Sorry" message immediately during visiting web page.

Question: how to design this solution?

- Option 1: Monolith. AtomicInteger. Can the CAS issue take place here? Or 1_000_000 is not that amount that cause an issue in this case? What is the number which can "do" that?
- Option 2: Monolith. sync should work here with no issues ?
- Option 3: Microservices. Redis INCR method.
  Is there are any options for microservices architecture? Is there a way to use MySql for this purpose?

Comment: What is "the CAS issue"?

Comment: Well, I think I did a mistake saying its an issue. In some specific scenario it might be slower than sync because : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11551963/can-synchronized-blocks-be-faster-than-atomics.

Comment: In that case, I'd say it doesn't matter here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Plain Old Java: Use in-memory synchronization using java lock semantics. You are correct about using AtomicInteger. However, this can only work if you have only one application instance running.
2. With MySql: There is a feature called [`select for update`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html) that helps you achieve what you are looking for. Whenever someone clicks on the link, you do `select for update` in MySql to see if the bonus is still available. If it is, you do update in DB in the same transaction. Meanwhile, all other parallel reads and writes will be blocked. Hence you get end-to-end fully atomic operation.
3. Redis won't work because even if `INCR` is atomic, the whole flow of reading the value from Redis, performing the business logic, and updating the value in Redis won't be atomic. E.g. Say the user count in Redis was `999_999` and 2 users concurrently click on the link. The application checks the count and it's under the threshold of `1_000_000` which means, both users are eligible for a discount and you end up giving a discount to both.

Comment: Thank you for 1 and 2. But I don't think I understand why 3 won't work? 
int value = Redis.GET ;
if (value < limit) value = Redis.INCR;
return (value < limit)  ? bonus :  0;

Comment: `value = Redis.INCR` after this statement, imagine, in a parallel thread, someone increases the count in redis. Now you are no more holding the latest count but a stale one in `value`.

Comment: Yes, its just the initial check. I.e. if the value already > limit means no point to continue. No bonuses already. Then I am try to use INCR which atomically (across the cluster) increments and get. So at this moment I already "reserved" bonus and are free to use it.

Comment: Got it. Yeah, it should work.